# probleme variable php into code jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i want load a content of a page .php or .html in a div named result, 
i created a function create file by a specifique extension in page php named script.php

in the index.php there is this code :

```
<?php
    session_start();
 $fichierCheminComplet = $_SESSION['fichierCheminComplet'];

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <style>
  ul{    list-style: none;    float:left;  }
  textarea{  margin:17px 10px;   height: 150px;width: 250px;}
  #result{ width: 252px;height: 100px;border: 2px solid #30ECB8;margin: -7px 113px;  }
</style>
</head>

<body>


    <ul>
    <li><input type="radio" value="php" id="inpt1"/>PHP</li>
    <li><input type="radio" value="html" id="inpt2"/>HTML</li>
    </ul>
    <textarea id="contenu"></textarea>
     <input type="button" id="btn" value="envoie">
<div id="result"></div>
 <script "text/javascript">
   $(function () {


 $("#btn").click(function () {


     var php = $('#inpt1').val();
     var html = $('#inpt2').val();
     var contenu = $('#contenu').val();

     alert(php + html + contenu);

     var sendData = {
         "php": php,
         "html": html,
         "contenu": contenu
     };


     $.post("script.php", sendData, function (data) {

         if (data == 1) {

             alert("creation de fichier");
             var lien = '<?php echo basename($fichierCheminComplet).PHP_EOL;?>';
             if (lien != "") {
                 $("#result").html("<p>non vide :) </p>");

                 $("#result").load(lien);
             } else {
                 $("#result").html("<p>vide :) </p>");
             }

         }

     });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

it worked if i delete those ligne :

```
var lien = '<?php echo basename($fichierCheminComplet).PHP_EOL;?>';
  if (lien != "") {
      $("#result").html("<p>non vide :) </p>");

      $("#result").load(lien);
  } else {
      $("#result").html("<p>vide :) </p>");
  }
```

the variable lien cant be readed :(

pliz help me

Comment: ok i've try another way :) thanks (y)

Comment: What is the variable lien?  Try simply echoing the same string to the page.  THe value of the variable lien is being set when you load the page (in php) not when the callback completes

Comment: ok thanks adam for the information (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always look at the result that the browser sees:

```
          var lien = 'sometexthere
';
```

Your `PHP_EOL` *est en trop*. Here's the correct way to "export" a PHP variable into JavaScript:

`var lien = <?php echo`[`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode)`(basename($fichierCheminComplet)); ?>;`

Comment: <?php
   session_start();
 $fichierCheminComplet = $_SESSION['fichierCheminComplet'];
  $lien = basename($fichierCheminComplet).PHP_EOL;
  print_r("<a class='lien'>".$lien."</a>");

?> then in js var lien =$(".lien").text();

 if(lien != ""){
 $( "#result" ).load(lien);
  }else{
    $( "#result" ).html("<p>vide :) </p>");
  }

Comment: Do not use `PHP_EOL`. It is not needed here.

Comment: but what it mean php_eol ?

Comment: `PHP_EOL` is a constant which indicates either `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n` depending on what OS your server is on. It is unnecessary in content that gets sent to the browser, and in this case harmful.